# What Am I doing wrong in the has many through association In Rails 6?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

So, I have 3 models(account, user_category, category) every model is inside different folders.
I've defined a has_many through association to associate `Account` to `Category` through middle table `User Category` so that a user can have many categories but it is not working as intended.

Account Model

```
module AccountBlock
  class Account < AccountBlock::ApplicationRecord
    ActiveSupport.run_load_hooks(:account, self)
    self.table_name = :accounts

    include Wisper::Publisher

    has_many :user_categories, class_name: "BxBlockCategories::UserCategory", dependent: :destroy
    has_many :categories, class_name: "BxBlockCategories::Category", through: "user_categories", dependent: :delete_all

end
```

User Category Model

```
module BxBlockCategories
  class UserCategory < ApplicationRecord
    self.table_name = :user_categories

    belongs_to :account, class_name: "AccountBlock::Account", foreign_key: :account_id
    belongs_to :category, class_name: "BxBlockCategories::Category", foreign_key: :category_id
  end
end
```

Category Model

```
module BxBlockCategories
  class Category < BxBlockCategories::ApplicationRecord
    self.table_name = :categories


    has_and_belongs_to_many :sub_categories,
                            join_table: :categories_sub_categories, dependent: :destroy

    has_many :contents, class_name: "BxBlockContentmanagement::Content", dependent: :destroy
    has_many :ctas, class_name: "BxBlockCategories::Cta", dependent: :nullify

    has_many :user_categories, class_name: "BxBlockCategories::UserCategory", dependent: :destroy
    has_many :accounts, class_name: "AccountBlock::Account", through: :user_categories
             
  end
```

[image: I've tried these things]

It works if I do category.account but returns an empty Association for account.categories.

Why is that?

I would love someone can help me.

I've included I've tried so far in the code above.

Comment: you're missing the `foreign_key` attributes on the `has_many` ... does this get fixed if you set them?

Comment: Can you please trim this down to the code thats actually relevant to the question? We don't need to know about your uploaders etc. Please also add the exception to the question as text. Screenshots are not an acceptable replacement.

Comment: @Jad I've done the same thing in one more project and I didn't specify the `foreign key` in those also but they work fine. Still I'll try to this too.

Comment: @Jad - why would `foreign_key` be neccisary when it can de derived from the names of these associations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I figured out what I was doing wrong.

In the Account Model file when I used `through: "user_categories"` I used a string literal which was causing the issue. Instead I had to use a symbol like this `through: :user_categories`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here isn't the assocations. It's that you're making a classic beginner misstake and calling an instance method on an whole collection of records.

Imagine you have an entire group of people in front of you and you ask "What is your name?" - how would that work? Are they all going to shout their names at the same time or just stare at your like you're an idiot?

If you want to get the categories for a given account you need to loop through the results:

```
AccountBlock::Account.first.categories.each do |category|
  puts category.name
end
```

The assocations are also very overcomplicated and you can get rid of a lot of over-configuration by just using the module nesting correctly:

```ruby
module AccountBlock
  # ApplicationRecord is resolved as AccountBlock::ApplicationRecord 
  class Account < ApplicationRecord 
    ActiveSupport.run_load_hooks(:account, self)
    self.table_name = :accounts
    has_many :user_categories, 
      # good - we are referring to a constant in another module.
      class_name: "BxBlockCategories::UserCategory", 
      dependent: :destroy
    has_many :categories, 
      class_name: "BxBlockCategories::Category", 
      through: "user_categories", 
      dependent: :delete_all
 end
end
```

```ruby
module BxBlockCategories
  class UserCategory < ApplicationRecord
    self.table_name = :user_categories
    # you don't need specify `foreign_key` when it can be derived from the name of the association. 
    belongs_to :account, class_name: 'AccountBlock::Account'
    belongs_to :category
  end
end
```

```ruby
module BxBlockCategories
  class Category < ApplicationRecord
    self.table_name = :categories
    has_many :user_categories, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :accounts, 
      through: :user_categories,
      class_name: 'AccountBlock::Account'
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you for answering I tried running a loop but It's still empty.

Comment: Well do you even have any records in the database? As I have already explained the issue isn't the assocations. Its whatever you think you're doing.

Comment: Yes I do have records in my database.